# regarding tcp tahoe and reno?

Tags: networking, network-programming, tcp

i want to know about the tcp tahoe and tcp reno?i have followed  kurose and ross book for networking and sally floyd paper but unable to understand and i also need some websites where i can find some viva questions based on tcp and socket programming?please help me.

Comment: The differences between tahoe and reno have no impact on socket programming.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've read the wikipedia articles on congestion: Reno/Tahoe are just ways to keep TCP from overreacting when packets are lost.

In the real world you'll sometimes get a dropped packet even though your network is not congested, and your connection tends to maintain the same throughput for its lifetime, so under normal conditions you should be able to figure out "hey, I can have N packets outstanding at once" pretty quickly, and if a packet gets lost I can almost always assume that I can get back to N right away unless there is a real outage.

So, these algorithms are just tweaks to the basic TCP congestion algorithm that try not to panic as much when packet losses occur.